# How do i determine exact PE image file size using its header(s)?

Tags: windows, delphi, language-agnostic, portable-executable

I need byte size, IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfImage appears to be rounded up to (unsure) boundary and is greater than real file size.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfImage` is the size of the loaded executable/dll in virtual memory.
It is not the same as the size on disk.

You can calculate it with `VirtualAddress + VirtualSize` of the last section.

`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfImage` is that value rounded up to the value of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SectionAlignment` (usually the same as the page size).

Answer (score 3):

```
if(LastSectionVirtualSize >= LastSectionSizeOfRawData)
{
    if( LastSectionVirtualSize % LastSectionSectionAlignment )
    {
        TempValue = LastSectionVirtualSize - (LastSectionVirtualSize % LastSectionSectionAlignment) + LastSectionSectionAlignment ;
    }
    else
    {
        TempValue = LastSectionVirtualSize ;    
    }
}
else
{
    if(LastSectionSizeOfRawData % LastSectionSectionAlignment)
    {
        TempValue = LastSectionSizeOfRawData - (LastSectionSizeOfRawData % LastSectionSectionAlignment) + LastSectionSectionAlignment ;
    }
    else
    {
        TempValue = LastSectionSizeOfRawData ;
    }
}

OH.SizeOfImage  = TempValue + dwLastSecRVA ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the accepted answer is incorrect. To get the executable's size on disk, you should calculate `PointerToRawData` + `SizeOfRawData` of the last section, not the virtual counterparts. For an example see http://www.strchr.com/creating_self-extracting_executables

Also note that some compilers like to append debug information after the last section. Be sure to strip any symbol tables or set release mode, depending on what compiler you use, for this to work.

Comment: I've found some things exist *outside* of sections such as the certificate table, take a look at KERNEL32.DLL for example, the relocation section ends followed by the certificate table, so as well as this I'd also check against the data directory table.

Comment: @Lloyd the signature is in an overlay outside the formal size of the image (on disk). And that also doesn't get mapped into memory.